# How to use jest.spyOn in wrapper.vm function?

Tags: jestjs, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-test-utils, vue-script-setup

I'm using vue-test-utils to test my components. They are written in composition API with `<script setup>` tag. I'm facing some difficulties when spying the functions to test if they were called or not. I'm wondering if I'm doing this correctly, as I can't spy anymore like before (Mycomponent.methods, for example.)

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
it('check if mounted emit is called', () => {
        wrapper.findComponent(ClientTableExpandable).vm.$emit('mounted');
        const buildListSpy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'buildList');

        expect(buildListSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
```

but I get the error:     `TypeError: object.hasOwnProperty is not a function`

Can someone help me out? I'm not interested in exposing the functions on my component so I thought spying on wrapper.vm was a good solution. If I mock like jest.fn is the same as nothing.